# Splitting a Complex query into individual Query for Readability

Tags: sql

I have a single complex Query of 1000 lines which i want to modify .Its very hard to understand the query.So is there any tool or Command for SQL to Split the SQL Query based on the tables involved in the Query.

For Example:A query involving two tables is split into 2 Queries of single tables:

```
SELECT 
   t1.c1,
   t2.c1,t2,c2 
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2;
```

Into

```
   1) SELECT 
       t1.c1  
    FROM table1 t1;

   2) SELECT 
       t2.c1,
       t2.c2 
    FROM table2 t2;
```

Similarly i have 75 tables joined together in a single query,which needs to  split into 75 single lines of select statement.

Comment: A simple join like that is not a complex query, and rarely can you break a query in two and have it mean the same thing. For one, in your example if table1 and table2 have respectively 5 and 10 rows, the first query will yield 50 results; the latter two will yield 5 and 10 results, respectively.

Comment: i love complex queries. people get afraid and won't touch them.

Comment: Why do you want to split the query? Just for readability?

Comment: I find the best way to improve a query's readability is to make use of white space in an appropriate and consistent manner as you would with code; as Gordon's edit to the question does.

Comment: What's wrong with the way you did it in your question?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  I have modified my question.Please comment if you need more clarity or  remove the hold on my question

Comment: @VijayManohar it makes no sense to "split" a join query. The best you can do is query the first table, and then query the second table repeatedly (based on the original join condition) while looping over the first queries results, and query the third repeatedly while looping over the second's results, and so on.... which could (depending on actual join conditions) leave you with a nested loop logic 75 layers deep.

Comment: @Uueerdo I am working on a legacy application where Database Queries are difficult to understand or written without proper approach,so asked if anyone uses any tool or logic that could solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

SQL SERVER : Try CTE table expression WITH clause or create VIEW per table or set of tables you think fit. This is so, keeping in mind that you should get same output as in original query.

Comment: But he is using MySQL ? @amit

Comment: Yup, i saw that tag later.